# Magento 2: Add additional attribute in mincart and checkoutcart after addToCart

Tags: magento2.2, event-observer

I try to add aaditional attribute using below way, but i got error like this

> Invalid method Magento\Quote\Model\Quote::addOption

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="vendor_module_checkout_cart_product_add_after" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**observer.php**

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;

class CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $checkoutSession;
    protected $_layout;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_request;
    protected $serializer;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
        Json $serializer = null
     )
    {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_layout = $layout;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->serializer = $serializer ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json::class);
     }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $post = $this->_request->getParams();
        // $item =  $observer->getQuoteItem(); // also try this but don't work it.
        $item = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
        $additionalOption = $additionalOptions = array();
        $additionalOption = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options');
        if (!empty($additionalOption)){
            $additionalOptions =  $this->serializer->unserialize($additionalOption->getValue());
        }
        if($post['attribute']){
            $additionalOptions[] = [
                        'label' => 'Test Attribute',
                        'value' => $post['attribute']
                    ];
        }
        if(!empty($additionalOptions)) 
        {
           $item->addOption(array(
                'product_id' => $post['product'],
                'code' => 'additional_options',
                'value' => $this->serializer->serialize($additionalOptions)
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

**addtocart.phtml**

```
<input type="hidden" name="attribute" id="attr_id" value="<?php echo $_product->getAttributeCode(); ?>" />
```

I also try all solution but can't get solution.

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-additional-options-in-magento-2/
https://magecomp.com/blog/add-additional-options-magento-2/
https://webkul.com/blog/additional-options-cart-item-magento2/

Comment: what is the error when you use `$item =  $observer->getQuoteItem(); ` this

Comment: $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();

When i use above code, can't get any data, display array is blank.

Comment: use getQuoteItem and remove`  if($post['attribute']){` condition or check if you are receiving attribute value with because this is the right way to do this with getQuoteItem.

Comment: @RakeshVarma i used it, but i can't get accentual result. Please provide me other solution if possible.

Comment: I know only this way to add `additional_options`

Comment: Yes, but i can't this. I don't know what happened there.

Comment: I have used your code and its working fine https://prnt.sc/lbodqt check this screenshot

Comment: Yes, It's working fine. I checked other project.
Thanks @RakeshVarma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Observer.php

Use below code

`$item =  $observer->getQuoteItem();`

replace with

```
$item = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
```